# I'm getting an error message using PyMc that I don't understand

Tags: python, pymc

Here is my setup and error message:

## creating fake data

```
  a=0.5
  b=-0.01
  s=1

ydata=np.empty((100, 100))

n, m =np.shape(ydata)
for t in range(1, n+1):
    phi_prob=s*((t**(-b))/a-1)
    process=Beta('process_%s' % str(t-1), value=0.5, alpha=s, beta=phi_prob)
    for i in range(m):
        ydata[t-1][i]=process.random()
#giving it some missing values, as that is part of the real problem I try to solve

for i, j in zip([choice(range(n)) for i in range(4*n)], [choice(range(m)) for j in range(4*m)]):
    ydata[i][j]=None

y_df=pd.DataFrame(ydata)
ydata=y_df.fillna(98) #making sure that it's all numeric, or else I get an error that I do understand
masked_data = np.ma.masked_equal(np.array(ydata), value=98)
```

## Building the model:

```
alpha=Beta("alpha", 1, 1)
time=np.arange(1, len(masked_data)+1)

@pymc.stochastic(observed=False)
def beta(value=-0.01):
    if (value >=0 or value <-0.5):
        return -np.inf #the constraint that beta must be between -0.5 and 0: note that log(0)=-inf 
    return -1.5 * np.log(1 + value ** 2)

@pymc.stochastic(observed=False)
def sigma(value=1):
    return -np.log(abs(value))

# Define phi as a deterministic function of alpha, beta and time
@pymc.deterministic
def phi_model(t=np.arange(1, 100), alpha=alpha, beta=beta, sigma=sigma):
    return sigma*((t**(-beta))/alpha-1)

y=np.empty(len(time), dtype=object) #numpy.empty(N, dtype=object)
```

## and here is the part of the model that throws the error:

```
for t in time:
    data=masked_data[time-1]
    y[t-1] = Beta('y %s' % str(t-1), value=masked_data[t-1], alpha=sigma, beta=phi_model, observed=True)
```

## here the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-412-a64e9ce685cf> in <module>()
      1 for t in time:
      2     data=masked_data[time-1]
----> 3     y[t-1] = Beta('y %s' % str(t-1), value=masked_data[t-1], alpha=sigma, beta=phi_model, observed=True)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/distributions.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    268                 random = debug_wrapper(random)
    269             else:
--> 270                 Stochastic.__init__(self, logp=logp, random=random, logp_partial_gradients = logp_partial_gradients, dtype=dtype, **arg_dict_out)
    271 
    272     new_class.__name__ = name

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/PyMCObjects.pyc in __init__(self, logp, doc, name, parents, random, trace, value, dtype, rseed, observed, cache_depth, plot, verbose, isdata, check_logp, logp_partial_gradients)
    703                         dtype=dtype,
    704                         plot=plot,
--> 705                         verbose=verbose)
    706 
    707         # self._logp.force_compute()

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/Node.pyc in __init__(self, doc, name, parents, cache_depth, trace, dtype, plot, verbose)
    199         self.extended_children = set()
    200 
--> 201         Node.__init__(self, doc, name, parents, cache_depth, verbose=verbose)
    202 
    203         if self.dtype is None:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/Node.pyc in __init__(self, doc, name, parents, cache_depth, verbose)
    117 
    118         # Initialize
--> 119         self.parents = parents
    120 
    121     def _get_parents(self):

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/Node.pyc in _set_parents(self, new_parents)
    138 
    139         # Get new lazy function
--> 140         self.gen_lazy_function()
    141 
    142     parents = property(_get_parents, _set_parents, doc="Self's parents: the variables referred to in self's declaration.")

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/PyMCObjects.pyc in gen_lazy_function(self)
    743                                     ultimate_args = self.extended_parents | set([self]),
    744                                     cache_depth = self._cache_depth)
--> 745         self._logp.force_compute()
    746 
    747 

LazyFunction.pyx in pymc.LazyFunction.LazyFunction.force_compute (pymc/LazyFunction.c:2411)()

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/distributions.pyc in wrapper(**kwds)
   2770     def wrapper(**kwds):
   2771         value = kwds.pop('value')
-> 2772         return f(value, **kwds)
   2773 
   2774     if arguments is None:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymc/distributions.pyc in beta_like(x, alpha, beta)
    708     # except ZeroProbability:
    709     #     return -np.Inf
--> 710     return flib.beta_like(x, alpha, beta)
    711 
    712 beta_grad_like = {'value' : flib.beta_grad_x,

error: (nb==1 || nb==len(x)) failed for hidden nb: beta_like:nb=99
```

Comment: Maybe this would be best answered on the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Please don't tell us we need to help you fast. That is obnoxious. You are asking strangers to volunteer to help you for free. Moreover, saying you need this fast will have no effect on when someone is able to provide an answer.